# Spaces in gensurf axis labels

Tags: octave

I'm on octave 3.8.0 and am using the fuzzy inference toolkit to do some work. I have two inputs and one output.

In my fis file I have (with obviously lots of other information):

```
[Input1]
name="InputVarOne"

[Input2]
name="InputVarTwo"

[Output1]
name="OutVar"
```

When I use `gensurf` to generate the surface plot, the axes are labeled with the name. However, when I put a space in the name, it cuts the name off (cuts off the character right before the space).

How can I get a space into the labels of the axes when using `gensurf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. After `gensurf` is called, you can change the labels using `[xyz]label`. So you can do:

```
gensurf(fis)
xlabel("Input Var One")
ylabel("Input Var Two")
zlabel("Out Var")
```